# How to load site on custom path with Redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to load my website on url `https://mysite.my/main` instead of default `https://mysite.my/`. But the following code gives me a mistake *Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.*

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Redirect from="/" to="/main" />
        <Route path="/main" component={App} />
      </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Inside `<App/>` component I have `<Route path="/main" component={Section} />`, but it doesn't seem that problem in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try swapping like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/main" component={App} />
        <Redirect from="/" to="/main" />        
      </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: hmmm, I've already tried this approach, but only know it's working correctly

Comment: It goes on how routes are matched. "/" matches every route, so that is why it would always fall there. "/" should always be the last one.